# Problem splitting HTTP body string in logic apps

Tags: arrays, string, azure, split, azure-logic-apps

I am using 'initialize variable' in my logic app and it is working correctly for:

```
split('a\nb\nc', '\n')
```

As it outputs:

```
["a","b","c"]
```

Whereas when I do this:

```
split(body('HTTP'),'\n')
```

It outputs it in one long string in the array with the `\n` like this:

```
["VALUE_A\nVALUE_B\nVALUE_C\nVALUE_D\nVALUE_E\n"]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The logic app reads `split(body('HTTP'),'\n')` as `split(body('HTTP'),'\\n')`. What you can do is go into code view and delete the escape character, `\`, for `\n` and it works.

The other way you can do it is by putting a return inside the split instead of `\n` like this:

```
split(body('HTTP'),'
')
```